What is the correct way to build a go package as c so to use in Android app?
i wrote a simple go package, and want to build it as a c so to use in an android app
compile os is ubuntu 22.04
this is the command
CGO_ENABLED=1 GOARCH=arm64 GOOS=android CC=aarch64-linux-android30-clang go build -buildmode=c-shared -o libadd.so main.go 

this is what i get
# file libadd.so 
libadd.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, Go BuildID=xxxxxxxxxxDp0s, with debug_info, not stripped

put the libadd.go in jniLibs and use in the app
System.loadLibrary("add");

when run the app, it log
18576-18602 ndk_translation Undefined instruction 0xd5380000 at 0x000077f7e5be6870
Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 18602 

the app can not start
which step is wrong?
What is the correct way to build a go package as c so to use in Android app?
thx
